# CN to include www on domain cert

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I generated my own certificate and used mysite.com as the common name. It works however if i go to www.mysite.com or any other subdomain i get a wrong domain msg. If i do *.mysite.com it works on all subdomains but not mysite.com. How do i get this to with the domain and sub?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Subject Alternative Names" extension, see on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) for explanation. See http://therowes.net/~greg/2008/01/08/creating-a-certificate-with-multiple-hostnames/ for an example on how to do that

Comment: I tried editing ssl's cfg and added subjectAltName = @alt_names [alt_names] DNS.1 = www.foo.com DNS.2 = www.foo.org inside of [ v3_req ]. I dont see any alt names inside of the cert. Also does this mean i need to change the ssl cnf file everytime i want a new req to change the alt domains?

Comment: Do you see X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: when generating the CSR ?

Comment: nope. (10 more to go..)

Answer (score 1):

I just [answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/160515/confusion-with-ssl-cert-and-apache/160530#160530) exactly that question from you yesterday!  You should generate a certificate with a `subjectAltName`.

Comment: oh hey that was me! that question was about how to get the domain name right. I had no idea what common name was about at the time! I tried generating a new cert and i dont see option come up and i dont see any .cnf file for the req i made. But note i am using CA.sh to generate these. I am going to check out the solution in the other answer.

Comment: I tried editing ssl's cfg and added subjectAltName          = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1   = www.foo.com
DNS.2   = www.foo.org inside of [ v3_req ]. I dont see any alt names inside of the cert. Also does this mean i need to change the ssl cnf file everytime i want a new req to change the alt domains?

Comment: I also tried `subjectAltName=DNS:host1.example.com,DNS:host2.example.org` and i tried again. I dont see the subjectAltName in the cert either.

Comment: Read my instructions again.  If you define subjectAltName in the [ v3_req ] section, then you also need subjectAltName=email:copy in the [ usr_cert ] section.